# Logging user out after some time of inactivity

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want user to be logged out  after some time inactivity. I want this php code to run automatically after some time of user inactivity. It must happen without refreshing the page.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_login_status'])) {
        $max_time = 5; // Maximun inactive time(this time is set in seconds )
        $current = time(); // Current time on server

        if (!isset($_SESSION['Inactive']))
        { // Create session inactive;
          Session::set('Inactive', time()); // Create session inactive;
        } else {
            $session_life = $current - $_SESSION['Inactive'] ;

           if ($session_life > $max_time )
            {

             Session::destroy(); // This is a function that destroys all sessions and logging out the user
             header('location: index.php'); // Redirects to some kinda page 
            } else {
                $_SESSION['Inactive'] = time();
            }

        }
    }
?>
```

This php code is working and user is logged out after 5 seconds when I refresh the page. But I need this code to be runned after those 5 seconds of inactivity and it should redirect to another page. I have tried some ajax code but it didn't worked.

Any suggestions how can I Run that php code after some time?

A lot of misspelled words. Sorry for that.

Comment: Your title says AJAX but you don't have any ajax code in there that I see. use a setTimeout() (or similar function) and when the time is up, call an ajax function that sends a request to a separate PHP file logging the user out, then upon return, refresh the window. Sorry for no code, but it's still an idea of how to get it to work.

Comment: To build on what @j_allen_morris said, you should monitor your user's activity on the page. If he is moving the mouse around and clicking on stuff, the setTimout should be reset to ensure the user isn't logged out while actually being active. SO users will not write code for you, so you will have to research this some more. I'm guessing you aren't very comfortable writing JavaScript which is why you are asking about this. I'd recommend looking up some tutorials online. If you run into trouble while trying to write the code, show it to us so we can review it.

Comment: I think most people use any navigation or page submission to determine if the person has been inactive too long, otherwise, the JS that @Jason is talking about will use some resources of the browser, maybe too many resources. Plus, I don't think javascript runs in the background if the user switches to a different window or tab. Then even if you're counting down activity, you don't get a true sense of how long the user has been away, but if on a submission you check the last time the user submitted something, then you're better off.  How long do you plan on setting this timer for?

Comment: @j_allen_morris you are probably right about the system resources thing. He would have to come up with a smart solution that wouldn't overcome the web browser with event triggers. That being said, from a user experience perspective, I can't stand automatic logouts. It usually results in a loss of important information/work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the code according to your needs. What this code would do is that if the user refreshes the page within 5 second, the timer will reset and start the count again. If user does not refresh/reload the page within 5 seconds, ajax call will be made to your controller action to log the user off.  Return a new url to the ajax call to automatically redirect user to a new page. [FYI, I do not like automatic logoffs, specially such short ones.  Of course, most Web servers have session timeouts. I would rather go with those timeouts.]

```
// add these functions at the bottom of the output html page within <script> tags
// YOU SHOULD CALL setLogoutTimer FUNCTION ON MOUSEMOVE OR SOME USER ACTIVITY EVENT.
// otherwise user will be logged out even when the user is doing something on the page



        setLogoutTimer();


    function setLogoutTimer() {
        var myTimeout;
        if (window.sessionStorage) {

            myTimeout = sessionStorage.timeoutVar;
            if (myTimeout) {
                clearTimeout(myTimeout);
            }

        }

        myTimeout = setTimeout(function () { logoutNow(); }, 5000);  //adjust the time. 
        if (window.sessionStorage) {
            sessionStorage.timeoutVar = myTimeout;
        }
    }

    function logoutNow() {
        if (window.sessionStorage) {
            sessionStorage.timeoutVar = null;
        }
        //MAKE AN AJAX CALL HERE THAT WILL CALL YOUR FUNCTION IN 
    // CONTROLLER AND RETURN A URL TO ANOTHER PAGE

    $.ajax({
            url: 'YOUR CONTROLLER ACTION URL',
            cache: false,
             async:false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (msg) {
                window.location.href=msg;  //msg is the url of another page returned by the controller


            }
        });



    }
```